# Cannot setSize JTextPane/JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, jtextpane

I have a JFrame with BorderLayout and I have a JTextPane/JScrollPane at NORTH  a splitpane in the CENTER and a JPanel with 4 JButtons on it at SOUTH. My Frame's size is (500, 470). I want the JTextPane to fill most of the window so I set its preferredSize to (500, 450) but it has no effect.

Here is a picture about what happens: http://postimg.org/image/3wslmppx7/

and here is my code:

```
public void initGUI()
{
    configWindow = new JFrame();
    configWindow.setTitle(node.getDispName()+ " [" + node.getIp() + "] configuration");
    configWindow.setSize(500, 470);
    configWindow.setLocation(TopologyMain.dim.width/2-configWindow.getSize().width/2, TopologyMain.dim.height/2-configWindow.getSize().height/2);
    configWindow.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    configPane = new JTextPane();
    configPane.setEditable(true);
    configPane.setName("Config");
    configPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 450));
    configPane.setBackground(Color.black);
    configPane.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(configPane);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 450));

    configWindow.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH); 

    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    //buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 20));
    GBC.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

    read = new JButton("Read");
    GBC.gridx = 0;
    GBC.gridy = 1;
    GBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    buttonPanel.add(read, GBC);

    apply = new JButton("Apply");
    GBC.gridx = 1;
    GBC.gridy = 1;
    GBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    buttonPanel.add(apply, GBC);

    load = new JButton("Load");
    GBC.gridx = 2;
    GBC.gridy = 1;
    GBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    buttonPanel.add(load, GBC);

    save = new JButton("Save");
    save.setEnabled(false);
    GBC.gridx = 3;
    GBC.gridy = 1;
    GBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    buttonPanel.add(save, GBC);

    configWindow.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, scrollPane, buttonPanel);
    splitPane.setEnabled(true);
    configWindow.getContentPane().add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    configWindow.setVisible(true);

    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `pack()` anywhere?

Comment: No, I do not use it.

Comment: Well, you probably should. Check [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--). Just remember to only call it after you added everything to the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution from [Gabriel Negut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/619252/gabriel-negut) in the comments:

Use `pack()` - but only call it after you have added everything to the window.

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--):

> public void pack()
>
> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred
>   size and layouts of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height
>   of the window are automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is
>   less than the minimum size as specified by the previous call to the
>   setMinimumSize method.
>
> If the window and/or its owner are not
>   displayable yet, both of them are made displayable before calculating
>   the preferred size. The Window is validated after its size is being
>   calculated.